# Login problem to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, windows

I attempt to connect to SQL Server 2008,I receive the following error.

> Login failed for user <>. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database.

By the way, I have a SQL Server 2008 R2 on Windows Server 2008 64-Bit Enterprise Edition.

Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This means you have logged in correctly to SQL Server, but the database in the connection string (or default database from CREATE LOGIN) is one of

- not there
- unavailable (eg autoclosed or recovering)
- no login-user mapping (eg CREATE USER as not been run)